# how to join multiple mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, multidimensional-array

i have a category tabale

```
parent_cat  cat_id title
0             1   fruit
0             2    vehicle
0             3    goods
1             4    sour
1             5    sweet
1             6    mixed
2             7    sedan
2             8     hatchback
2             9     car
```

and product table

```
offer_name parent_cat sub_cat
mango         1        4,6
maruti        2        7,8,9
apple         1        5,4
```

i want to join the table according the requested get parameter
if ?title=fruit then i will get mango,apple and my sql query is

```
SELECT category.cat_id,category.title,product.parent_cat,product.offer_name 
FROM category, product 
WHERE category.cat_id=product.parent_cat 
AND category.title='fruit' --requested get variable

output is :  cat_id  title  parent_cat  offer_name
               1     fruit      1          mango
               1     fruit      1          apple
```

if ?title=sour then i will get mango,apple and my sql query is

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE CONCAT(',' , sub_cat , ',') LIKE '%,4,%'

output is : offer_name parent_cat  sub_cat
                mango     1           4,6
                 apple    1           4,5
```

my question is how to convert sour which id is 4 in place of '%,4,%'  .so that i can put the get variable over there.how to join like 1st mysql query

Comment: ok but can you rephrase the query again ,it will be helpful @Strawberry

Comment: SELECT category.cat_id,category.title,product.parent_cat,product.offer_name 
FROM category, product 
WHERE category.cat_id=(SELECT * FROM product WHERE CONCAT(',' , sub_cat , ',') LIKE '%,4,%')
AND category.title='fruit'      result nothing @Strawberry

Comment: This schema doesn't fit in with the relational database model because it violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of proper
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If you can restructure it to be a proper one-to-many relationship it would be way easier to write a query and the query would run significantly faster.

Comment: can you recode how to achive offer name mango and apple if ?title=sour @tadman

Comment: It's not a question of if I can do it, but if you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested you should consider redesigning your database in a proper relational way. But it is possible to get what you are looking for with the following query:

```
SELECT offer_name, parent_cat, sub_cat FROM product JOIN
(SELECT cat_id FROM category WHERE title = 'sour') AS temp ON
CONCAT(',',sub_cat,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',temp.cat_id,',%')
```

Answer (score 1):

if a product belongs to multiple categories you should have multiple rows in your table. it`s a many to many relationship. and your sql should be SELECT * FROM product WHERE sub_cat in ( ... )

Comment: ok but can you rephrase the query again ,it will be helpful  @user3642242  and thank you

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: you can't.

MySQL cannot deal with comma separated lists. You basically have two choices:

#### #1 Make two queries

Basically get the `cat_id` first and then do the second query as in your example. But then you don't avoid the `LIKE '%,4,%'`.

#### #2 Do it the relational database way.

As mentioned by user3642242 you have a many-to-many-relationship. Usually in SQL you would use another relationship table in this case. So you would have a `category`, `product` and `category_product_relationship` table.
Your `category_product_relationship` table would then look like this:

```
category_id  product_id
1            1
1            3
2            2
...          ...
```

It means that the product table needs an index, which is a good idea anyway since SQL loves Primary Keys and is super fast with them.

You would then do a `JOIN` to query your products like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM category c
JOIN category_product_relationship r ON r.category_id = c.cat_id
JOIN product p ON p.id = r.product_id
WHERE c.title = 'sour'
```

(c, r and p are aliases)

You can then remove the `parent_cat` and `sub_cat` columns from your `product` table and handle all of that through the relationship table.